# Trying to ground ADC0832 properly

Tags: digital-logic, analog, adc, ground, grounding

**I trying to use ADC0832 for voltage and current measurement** on Raspberry Pi 4, previously I was using **MCP3008** for that purpose. But I want to simplify the system.

So, I am trying to implement ADC0832, but I stuck on the grounding, for MCP3008 I was using 2 different grounds **Analog ground** and **Digital ground**, as it indicated in datasheet.

But now, **ADC0832 have only one ground** on DIP-8, how can I ground this IC properly? I looked the datasheet but I can't find specific information.

Comment: Can you provide datasheet links?

Comment: "I was using 2 different grounds Analog ground and Digital ground": a common misunderstanding on the role of these two pins on generic A2D chips (I did not look up the specific datasheet for your MCP part) - in the future provide a datasheet link. These pins are typically connected together, just like @justme describes.

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet does have pictures.

The chip has one ground pin so that's what you have to use for grounding it.

It is unclear how you used the previous chip but you might have used it wrong - the analog and digital ground pins need to be connected externally together right at the chip so technically it too has just one ground connection to ground but it just has two pins instead of only one ground connection.